# Capacitor in circuit for potentiometer?

Tags: capacitor, potentiometer, display

In a German tutorial video about [EAGLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE), starting at [1:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=YoVen9os4Sk&t=4515) the author adds a trim potentiometer for regulating the contrast of an *A162* display. Between the slider and ground he adds a 100 nF capacitor.

What is the capacitor for?

Screen shot showing the circuit with capacitor *C4*:

[image: Screen shot of YouTube video]

Note that the author stresses that the video is about the *basic features of EAGLE*, not about circuit design and not even about good layout of a circuit. He says that he didn't build the circuit, and it may not work. The tutorial is very good —  I learned using EAGLE from scratch.

Comment: Do you know what the chip is? Do you know if pin 3 is input or output?

Comment: @Andyaka The author of the video says that that the display component A162 exists, and that there is a datasheet. That's all I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The capacitor filters noise, making the voltage at `V0` more stable. A capacitor resists changes in voltage. The rate of change of voltage, current, and capacitance are related by:

$$ I = C \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} $$

The larger the capacitance, the more current required to make a change in voltage. Since there is only so much noise current, the more capacitance, the less the voltage noise.

Possible sources of noise:

- [electromagnetic interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference)
- [thermal noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise)
- noise from the wiper sliding in the potentiometer
- noise from the power supply
- leakage currents from other digital IO

Another way to view it: the capacitor and resistor together make a low-pass [RC filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_filter). This attenuates higher frequencies, while not attenuating the lower frequency. Since you are interested in the nearly constant voltage selected by the potentiometer, and the lowest frequency is a voltage that doesn't change at all, this is good.

Comment: Phil, do you know what the chip is or if it's an output it's connected to??

Comment: @Andyaka I'm guessing it's an LCD display module like [this one](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/datasheet/LMB162ABC-Manual-Rev0.2.pdf). The V0 pin is an input, and controls the display contrast.

Comment: I was also thinking: A capacitor behaves like a rechargeable battery. Properties: 1. It provides the voltage with which it was charged. 2. When charging, it initially has low resistance.

Let's say the potentiometer was untouched for some time, and now I move it abruptly. When the resistance between slider and ground drops, then for a brief moment the capacitor provides the previous voltage (1), preventing an abrupt drop in voltage. When that resistance increases, then for a brief moment the capacitor's resistance drops (2), preventing an abrupt change in resistance, thus voltage.

Comment: @feklee That's a little bit right, but also wrong. [The resistance of a capacitor does not change with time](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77547/why-do-rc-circuit-voltages-decay-slowly-rather-than-instantly/77588#77588).

Answer (score 1):

The VO pin is the power to the LED segments.  The amount of current drawn on this pin may vary somewhat as the display is scanned, in a matter which will vary with display content.  This can cause annoying horizontal streaks on the display.  Adding a capacitor will ensure that any variations in voltage that may result from changing current demands are slow enough that they affect the display uniformly.